# C# Visual Studio WSDL import generates wrong classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, visual-studio-2015, wsdl

I need to develop a web service, I received the WSDL (with HORRIBLE unintuitive field names), so I decided to import it as a Service Reference in Visual Studio 2015 to get the classes and the methods to call.

This is the WSDL (I'm sorry I'll need to use pastebin for the characters limit in the body of a question):

http://pastebin.com/B4pFH3jY

The generated code can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/Y9ehXQxy

When I try to build I get several errors:

- `public partial class Z_CA_WS_ARS_AFC_GET_SCH_CC` has the same name of an interface, so I get error.
- Lot of items argue about not having as parameter the interface (as it is considered the partial class)

I tried to rename the partial class, but I don't know in the remaining code where I should change and call the class or the interface. The names, as I previously said, don't really help.

When I import in Visual Studio I use the following (default) advanced settings, maybe it helps.

[image]

Is there any way to import the WSDL with no issues without asking for a new version (it seems correct to me)?

I even tried to use svcutil with no luck, maybe I used the wrong version.

Thanks for help.